# PDO Insert Array Using Key As Column Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am inserting the $_POST contents of my PHP array into a table with PDO. I was looking at the following lines of code and I had one of those "there has to be a better way to do this" moments. If the key name matches the column name in the table, is there a more simple way to insert all of it?

Code for example:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `applications`(`username`, `email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

$statement->execute(array($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['name']));
```

This code WORKS but it just seems a bit over-the-top (especially as more and more columns are added).

Comment: Use [`bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and iterate through an array of the columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do it this way:

Declare the columns first.  We'll use these to extract a subset of $_POST for use as columns.  Otherwise a user could pass bogus request parameters that don't match any columns of the table, which would break our SQL.

```
$columns = array('username','email','password','name');
$column_list = join(',', $columns);
```

Create named parameter placeholders i.e. `:username`.

```
$param_list = join(',', array_map(function($col) { return ":$col"; }, $columns));
```

Form the SQL separately, because it's easier to read and debug if it's in its own variable.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `applications` ($column_list) VALUES ($param_list)";
```

*Always* check for error status returned from `prepare()` and `execute()`.

```
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
if ($statement === false) {
  die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
}
```

Here we take *only* the fields of $_POST that match the columns we want to insert.

```
$param_values = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($columns));
```

And pass that array to `execute()`.  Again, check for error return status.

```
$status = $statement->execute($param_values);
if ($status === false) {
  die(print_r($statement->errorInfo(), true));
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `array_intersect_key` to "minimize" the `$_POST` array?

Comment: @Blazemonger, to ensure that the user can't spoof the POST parameters and break your app.

Comment: i have the same issue but i am working inside a class and the values are not getting from $_POST its coming as a parameters, any idea? please.

Comment: @MasoudMustamandi, you can't use the function argument instead of the $_POST array?

Comment: No, i did something like this, now it works


 $param_values = array_combine($columns, $values);