# inserting form values into an array using foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

i have this long form that requires multiple inputs, how can i properly insert these inputs into an array using a foreach loop?

assuming i have these:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$age= $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
...etc..
```

instead of typing such this..

```
$myarray = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name,'color'=>$color,'age'=>$age,'gender'=>$gender,'location'=>$location,etc...);
```

how can i let `foreach` loop insert the appropriate values into the array?

Comment: $_POST is already an array.

Comment: @vlcekmi3: $_POST is already an array and you are making it 2d.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [PDO Insert Array Using Key As Column Name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13545354/1415625)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is this

```
$myarray = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
   $myarray[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I was writing exactly this answer. Sorry, can't vote due to reached daily voting limit.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myarray = $_POST;
```

This is enough. `$_POST` is already an array as **Suresh Kamrushi** stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = array();
foreach ($_POST as $post){
$myarray[] = $post;
}
```

**Edit**
As correctly pointed out in the comments below, `$myarray = array_values($_POST);` works too.

Comment: The question is not very clear. But your `foreach` loop is useless. You can simply do `$myarray = array_values($_POST);` instead.

Comment: This is a useless `foreach` loop

Comment: @AmalMurali - Yep, that would do too. David, it's what the OP apparently asks for even though no abundance of info given in the question.