# PDO Insert values from subarrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url_id"]=>
    string(2) "45"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["h"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}

echo $column_list = join(',', $items);
...
```

This [PDO Insert Array Using Key As Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545170/pdo-insert-array-using-key-as-column-name) helps me inserting array values in MySQL table easily. But now I do have an array containing subarrays and it looks like this `join(',', $items);` does not work. Guess you think "of course it doesn't work" right now, but how can I store the keys and the values into a variable to use `$sql = "INSERT INTO applications ($column_list) VALUES ($param_list)";` successfully.

I have tried `array_merge` but that did not work at all. I would like to show some code examples, but I have no idea what to try and how to achieve that.

Thanks for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Get keys/values with a `foreach`

Comment: And save those in a new array?

Comment: [look it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)